# Reactive Radio doesn't get set after render

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

so basically it is like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4mxRdHHZp5mcFoLKDjg?p=preview)

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-control" *ngFor="let item of foods">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="food" value="{{item}}"> {{item}}
  </div>
</form>
```

A very simple reactive form.

However, when I put the exactly code in my real project. It doesn't work.

I can see it is trying to set the checked property as true

on this line [this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'checked', this._state);](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/45ddd6ba78b5c9a6994b800f77a0499abb5b9b1a/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/radio_control_value_accessor.ts#L121)

But it doesn't mark as checked on screen after it loaded.

If I change the type to checkbox, it works fine.

If I use ngModel, it works fine as well.

I don't know what else can go wrong.

Update:

I tested it on a different [starter](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter)

It doesn't work too.

The component looks like

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
   <div *ngFor="let x of foods">
      <input type="radio" value="{{x}}"  formControlName="food"> {{x}}
   </div>
  </form>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  form;
  foods = ['beef', 'lamb', 'fish'];

  constructor(private _FormBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this._FormBuilder.group({
      food: 'lamb'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Two suggestions. Normally when I do this I add it to ngOnInit. Also shouldn't it be like this, food:['lamb_2'], or if you want to add validators like this, , ["lamb_2", Validators.required], http://plnkr.co/edit/1bqc4fvrAnL1EdMqYk0d?p=preview

Comment: yeah, I know. I tried both of them. Doesn't work. The only different I can think of is I used webpack 2.2.1 for my real project. And I used systemjs on plunker

Comment: Interesting. I had a problem kind of similar to this and I switched to FormGroup and FormControl then added the default value in as a parameter, which fixed my problem. Since your implementation is so small maybe try writing it out instead of using FormBuilder to at least see if that solves the issue.

Comment: tried that one too. I have to admit it is so weird. I have 2 projects, and none of them works. I used [angular2 class starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), but somehow I can't run it successfully now. It is like everything collapsed at the same time  :(

Comment: Man I have also had a lot of random problems that start out of no where. I think some how webpack gets corrupt after compiling sometimes. Did you try deleting node_modules and reinstalling? Also many times I have had to do things like that and update everything. Some libraries also break when not ran with the correct version of other libraries.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. And to avoid the issue you said, I use yarn. I even tried it on different node version, 6.70,  6.9.5, 7.2. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. 2 days. This is a tough one. I didn't think this is possible. Apparently, it was a known issue from [@ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1125)

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p4mxRdHHZp5mcFoLKDjg?p=preview) to repeat it.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,ReactiveFormsModule,    
    NgbModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```